# Properly show submenu using css

Tags: css

I tried for a few hours now to figure out why my sub menu disappear when I hover over the parent menu.

Live demo: http://topforexbroker.net/kafi/

I could possibly remove the margin-top from my sub-menu class and easy fix but then my border 1px at the top of the sub menu goes away :)

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Demonstration of the issue: https://gyazo.com/5387a96e4c86f4fb1cbef9aa8715ed71

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve the problem, as I said in my first post this margin.. I changed some of them on the sub-menu class and the primary-menu and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thing wrong with your CSS. I usually add a timeout like 200ms before hide sub-menu to avoid this situation.

Comment: Can you give me an example? :) I guess some sort of transition?

Comment: Hum. I didn't read your source code. Are you using javascript for showing submenu?

Comment: No Im using plain css

Comment: Hum. In that case, I have no idea. :( . Sorry.

Comment: No problem @thangngoc89

Comment: Yes. I know the issue. It's a common issue of submenu. (you should edit your answer with that gif).

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is related to your jQuery script and is not a CSS issue. Im assuming there is some sort of event listener probably

```
.mouseleave()
```

which has a function to hide your submenu. Change that and this behavior will go away.

https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/